# PySide : Children objects not destroyed on close of parent object

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have the following code :

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

class Main_Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main_Window,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.navigateur=QtGui.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.navigateur)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 600)
        self.window =QtGui.QWidget(None,QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.window.grid=QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.window.button=QtGui.QPushButton("quit",parent=self.window)
        self.window.button.setObjectName("test")
        self.window.button.clicked.connect(self.try_close)
        self.window.grid.addWidget(self.window.button)
        self.window.setLayout(self.window.grid)
        self.window.setFixedSize(self.window.sizeHint())
        self.fwindow=self.navigateur.addSubWindow(self.window,QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.show()

    def try_close(self):
        self.fwindow.close()
        print(self.window.findChild(QtGui.QPushButton,"test"))

def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_wdw=Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

According to the documentation, when I close self.window, all children of self.window should be deleted however it doesn't seem to be the case since the print function prints something like PySide.QtGui.QPushButton object at...

What is going wrong ?

Comment: self.window.close() only closes the content of the window but doesn't close the window "frame" (title bar, status bar and center area), but even when using self.window.close(), the result is the same, the object isn't destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try_close` method is not a good test, because it does not allow the necessary events to be processed before checking for child objects.

If a separate method is added for the check, e.g:

```
def initUI(self):
    ...
    menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
    menu.addAction('Test', self.test)

def test(self):
    for w in QtGui.qApp.allWidgets():
        print(w.objectName(), w)
```

You will see that the widget with objectName "test" and its QPushButton child do get deleted once the close/deletion events have been processed.

Answer (score 3):

In Qt, the `QObject` are not deleted immediatly (see [QObject::deleteLater()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) method). In Python, the object are deleted by the garbage collector.

So, your widget could be stayed in memory during a laps before the deletion.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but ekhumoro's explanation answers better my question.